# Using window.location to style

Tags: javascript, html, css, window.location

So i have this project i am working on and i am trying to hide/show some elements based on the auth status. I managed to get all the other elements to work as i wanted but i have a problem with one particular element.I have an upload form which i want to be shown only if the user is logged in. 
Here is my form:

```
<form id="addVideo" class="uploadForm">
        <h3>Alege fisier:</h3>
        <input id="fileUpload" type="file" required>
        <input id="caption" type="text" required>            
        <button id="buttonSubmit" onclick="uploadFile()">Submit </button>
</form>
```

And this is my JS:

```
const btnLogin = document.getElementById('modalBtn');
const btnLogout = document.getElementById('logout');
const contentUploader = document.getElementById('addVideo');
const btnAcasa = document.getElementById('acasa');
const btnBiblioteca = document.getElementById('biblioteca'); 

const setUI = (user)=>{
if(user){
btnLogin.style.display='none';
btnLogout.style.display='block';
if(window.location == 'biblioteca.html'){
  contentUploader.style.display ='block'; 
}     
btnAcasa.style.display='block';
btnBiblioteca.style.display ='block'; 
}
else{
btnLogin.style.display = 'block';
btnLogout.style.display = 'none';
if(window.location === 'biblioteca.html'){
  contentUploader.style.display = 'none'; 
}    
btnAcasa.style.display ='block';
btnBiblioteca.style.display ='block'; 
}
```

}
I am using window.location because i run this script on 2 different pages.
Here is how i call the function:

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user =>{
if(user){
  setUI(user);    
  console.log(user);
}
else{
setUI()    
console.log(user);
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`Window.location` returns the Location object, which would not be equal to a string.
 Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

you could use

```
if(window.location.href == 'biblioteca.html'){
  contentUploader.style.display ='block'; 
}
```

But here also you need to consider the domain name and everything that comes before `biblioteca.html`

Comment: `window.location.href.includes("biblioteca.html")` is better